# Find how many arguments are being used in a printf() statement

Tags: php, variables, printf

Given some unknown input, how do you tell which variables are being substituted into a `(s)printf` statement?

```
printf("%s %s", "a", "b");     // both used
printf("%s",    "a", "b");     // only the first one used
printf('%1$s %1$s', "a", "b"); //      "        "
printf('%s %1$s', "a", "b");    //     "        "
printf('%1$s %s %1$s', "a", "b");   // "        "
printf('%2$s', "a", "b");      // only the second one used.
```

Checking the resultant string for the presence of the first or second variables won't help, because they could have the same value.

In my own situation, there is only ever 2 variables that could be substituted, and I need to know whether the second one is used or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit hackish function to do it:

```
function printf_and_return_min_args_required(/* var args */) {
    $old_track = ini_set('track_errors', '1');
    $args = func_get_args();
    $args2 = array();
    $required = 100;    
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        $args2[] = $arg;
        if (@call_user_func_array("printf", $args2)) {
            $required = count($args2) - 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    ini_set('track_errors', $old_track);
    return $required;
}
```

For `sprintf()` you might have to return `array($result, $required)` instead if you don't want the `$result` printed by the function.

Answer (score 2):

Parse the format string yourself and see how many args it expects.

EDIT: A psuedocode example (no error checking):

```
bool arg1used = false;
bool arg2used = false;
int unspecifiedscount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if s[i] != '%' continue;
    switch s[i+1] {
        case '%':
            i++;
            break;
        case 's':
            if unspecifiedscount == 0 arg1used = true;
            if unspecifiedscount == 1 arg2used = true;
            break;
        case '1':
            if s[i+2] == '$' && s[i+3] == 's' {
                arg1used = true;
                i+=3;
                true;
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            if s[i+2] == '$' && s[i+3] == 's' {
                arg2used = true;
                i+=3;
                true;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, that was pretty much exactly what I was asking for help with.

Comment: One way would be to walk the string looking for % characters.

If you see %1$s or your first %s, set a flag indicating the first variable is used. Likewise for %2$s or your second %s.

Comment: @nickf, in other words, how do you suppose the printf() implementation itself figures it out?  Then do that.  :P  Which means looking for %.  (Note %% becomes %.)

Comment: There's a lot of things to consider however. For example: `sprintf("%% %s", "a", "b") == "% a"`, whereas `sprintf("% % %s", "a", "b") == "% b"`.

Comment: Also: `sprintf("% % % %s", "a", "b") == "% %s"` and sprintf("% % % % %s", "a", "b") ==> error, too few args`.

Comment: Like I said, walk the string. I'll edit something in.

You could also regex something up, but unless you're comfortable with regular expressions I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a kludgey way which works in this situation, but would be interested to hear better solutions which are more generic.

```
if (($result = @sprintf($input, "a")) === false) {
    // need two arguments
    $result = sprintf($input, "a", "b");
} else {
    // only needed one argument
}
```

Basically, it just tries it with one argument, and if that didn't work, then you know it needs two.